# expected unqualified-id error with template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to overwrite the default constructor of a template class, but keep getting an

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./test.h:11:23: error: expected unqualified-id
class Argon<D>::Argon(){
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

error from clang.

This is my source code:

```
//test.h
#include <iostream>

template <typename A>
class Argon{
    public:
        Argon();
};


template <typename D>
class Argon<D>::Argon(){
    std::cout<<"Argon constructor"<<std::endl;

}
```

with test.h being included in the main.cpp file.

```
#include "test.h"

int main(){
}
```

Comment: Typo; Remove the `class` from `class Argon<D>::Argon(){`

Comment: How would you define a *non* template constructor? Or any normal member function? You *have* done it before, haven't you?

Comment: Nathan Oliver is of course right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining a method, the `class` keyword does not belong there.

```
template <typename D> Argon<D>::Argon(){
    std::cout<<"Argon constructor"<<std::endl
}
```